# JQuery Replace Attribute Source Not Working

Tags: jquery

I have a button named "on" (on.png) and a button named "off" (off.png). They are designed to act as on/off switches, so when clicked, the other should load. Since I don't want to deal with the path (which is the same for both), I am trying to do an attribute replace. The jQuery code below, however, does nothing and I can't find the error. Any help is appreciated.

```
$('#btnDining').css({'cursor':'pointer'}).on('click', function(e){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $(this).attr('src', function(i, src){
      return (src.indexOf('off.png')!=-1)?src.replace("_off","_on"):src.replace("_on","_off");
   });
}); // end button click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-complicating things. Try something like this:

```
$('#btnDining').css('cursor','pointer').on('click', function(e){
   this.src = /_off/.test(this.src) ? 
        this.src.replace("_off","_on") : 
        this.src.replace("_on","_off");
}); // end button click
```

Also, consider using a CSS background-image as you will have more effective and cleaner code if you simply toggle classes and swap background images instead.

Comment: code is fine but background image and toggling classes is much smarter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that :

```
$('#btnDining').css({'cursor':'pointer'}).on('click', function(e){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   src = (src.indexOf('off.png')!=-1)?src.replace("_off","_on"):src.replace("_on","_off");

   $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

And I think, it's a more readable way..

Comment: This killed all the scripts on the page but I don't see a syntax error.

Comment: I fixed it, forgot a '(' ! Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are define `src` in the function scope of the outer function, then redefining it in the inner function scope.

```
$('#btnDining').css({'cursor':'pointer'}).on('click', function(e){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $(this).attr('src', function(i, source){
      return (src.indexOf('off.png')!=-1)?src.replace("_off","_on"):src.replace("_on","_off");
   });
}); // end button click
```

I'm not sure which `src` is which. However, changing the function variable name in the attr function should fix your issue.

Comment: Do I not have to pass in the 'scr' from the outer function to the inner function? If not, then I don't need the var src line at all.